# Apps on memory card taking internal memory

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, sd-card, app2sd

I noticed that many apps that are, according to Android, installed on the memory card are actually taking internal memory space, as when I delete their data or uninstall them I notice a change on the phone memory, and no on the SD. Why does this happens? I am moving my apps wrongly?.

I run Cyanogen Mod, and some of the apps are ones that should not be moved (according to the app App2SD) or that couldn't be moved (but moved them anyways via other apps).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*App2SD* doesn't move the entire app to SDcard, just parts of it. That's normal (or rather "works-as-designed"), and no error on your end.

Please also see our [apps2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), where alternatives are listed along. Note however that those alternatives require root access on the device. Methods like [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd) are able to move the entire app; *Data2SD* and Simple2Ext can even move its data.